# Hide column name in personalization dialog box based on condition

Tags: sapui5

I have p13n dialog box in a table, where I am displaying 2 columns coming from the backend.
 [image]

Now, I want to implement condition in column 2. For example,

```
if(mainCondition === true)
{
  display column2;
}
else
{
 hide columns2;
}
```

The issue here is, these column names are coming from CDS view & with entity set.

I can, of course, hide them completely using the *setIgnoreFromPersonalisation* method, however, I don't know how can I implement condition on these field's visibility property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two columns are coming from the backend, you can add Filter to the model to filter out the ones to be hidden.